# Meteor template reference in <head>

Tags: html, meteor

I have a Meteor template (in a separate HTML file in the client directory) called "head" and I want to do this:

```
<head>
    {{> head}}
</head>
```

Meteor seems to ignore this and instead just renders the text `{{> head}}` on the HTML page.

Can I reference my header through Meteor or do I have to put it directly into my non-template HTML?

Also, I would like to receive an answer, not a reason why I should not be doing this. :)

Comment: just tried it, same result.   Documentation implies it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not supported:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/266

Just use normal DOM manipulation to achieve that. E.g. to change document title:

```
Tracker.autorun(function () { 
  var pageTitle = Session.get('pageTitle'); 

  // only change title if we have one so that we preserve initial title 
  if (pageTitle){ 
    document.title = "My Awesome Site " + pageTitle; 
  } 
});
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/meteor-core/Q_XYXM5WNdo/42G9Eh4EcswJ